# Drag and Drop ListBox Rows with jQuery in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a C# drag and drop with a listbox.

I've come across some snippets of code on the internet but none seem to be working with my needs.

I want you to show me an example code of how to move rows in ListBox.

My code below.

Thanks!

[image]

**.cs**

```
public partial class DragDrop : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
            string query = "SELECT * FROM City LIMIT 10;";

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(ds);
                            ListBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                            ListBox1.DataTextField = "Name";
                            ListBox1.DataValueField = "Name";
                            ListBox1.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**.aspx**

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".drag_drop_grid").sortable({
                items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
                cursor: 'crosshair',
                connectWith: '.drag_drop_grid',
                axis: 'y',
                dropOnEmpty: true,
                receive: function (e, ui) {
                    $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
                }
            });
            $("[id*=ListBox2] tr:not(tr:first-child)").remove();
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"
                    SelectionMode="Multiple"
                    Height="100"
                    Width="100"
                    Font-Names="Verdana"
                    EnableViewState="true"></asp:ListBox>

                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server"
                    Height="100" 
                    Width="100"
                    Font-Names="Verdana"></asp:ListBox>

            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this can help you.
Best regards

http://rajudasa.blogspot.com/2011/11/drag-and-drop-list-items-with-multi.html

Here you will find information about selecting items by drag-n-drop on webpage and how i created drag-n-droppable items in listBoxes using JQuery-UI Sortable.

On JQuery-UI Sortable Demo page, List items been represented by `<li>`, I tried with `<li>` and `<td>` as items, both of them not satisfied my requirement. Instead of using `<li>` as items, I used `<div>` tags. One of the required feature is, multi-select drag drop using `ctrl + mouse drag`.

The sample demo page contains 2 Listboxes (source, destination). Source box is filled with items from JSON data(static or coming from Asp.Net). On button click, the selected/dropped items in destination box
are stored in a hidden-field as JSON string and you can retreive them at serverside. (or in JS version, just filling in a textarea).

You can check the [demo here](https://rajudasa-d36bf.firebaseapp.com/blog/dragdrop)

Download the [Zip file here](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B-Hj9WJDQAz5TFhJVlhvNXQta0U)